# How do I apply ∂/∂x in these examples?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

If we have a function $ f(x,y(x)) $ it is clear to me that

$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} \tag{A}
$$

so $ \frac{df}{dx} \neq \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $

It is explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296259/partial-derivative-vs-total-derivative), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99662/derivative-over-variable-vs-partial-derivative-over-variable), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229227/straight-vs-partial-derivative) the difference between $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ and $ \frac{d}{dx} $. That is, partial differentiation is when you hold one variable constant (even if it is dependent on the other) and differentiate with respect to the other. "Total differentiation" is when you "transform" $ f(x,y(x)) $ into a single-variable function $ \gamma(x) $ and find $ \frac{d\gamma}{dx} $. (In this case, at least)

1. Let's say you have a function $ g(x(t),y(x(t))) $ and you wish to find $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} $ ( NOT $ \frac{dg}{dt}) $. You can "transform" it into a new function $ h(t, y), j(x, t), k(x) $, or $m(t)$. When trying to find $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} $ which new function do we use? Does it even matter? Does taking the partial derivative even make sense in this case?
2. Similarly, returning to $ f(x,y(x)) $ and using the chain rule to find $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $:
   $$
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \tag{B}
   $$
   Surely $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $, so this must mean $ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0 $. Am I applying the chain rule correctly, and if I am, can someone explain this result? I always thought that partial differentiation and "total differentiation" are the same in the context of a single-variable function $ y $ which means (A) must equal (B). This is a contradiction.

Overall, I'm confused on the dynamics of partial differentiation when multiple variable are dependent on another.

Comment: Instead of writing $df/dx,$ which when you think about it seems a little strange, I've always found it clearer to define $g(x) = f(x,y(x)).$ Then $dg/dx$ makes perfect sense, and you differentiate using the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

You are differentiating the composition of two functions:$F:R\rightarrow R^2$ defined by $F(x)=(x,y(x))$ its differential at $x$ is a linear function from $R$ to $R^2$ evaluated at $1$ you have $dF=(1,dy/dx)$ and the function $G:R^2\rightarrow R$ defined by $G(x,y)=f(x,y)$ its differential  at $(x,y)$ is a linear function from $R^2$ to $R$ $dG(u,v)=\partial_xfu+\partial_yfv$ $u,v\in R$. The formula of the differential of the composition of two functions also applies here:

$d(G\circ F)=dG(F(x))\circ F'(x)=\partial_xf+\partial_yfdy/dx$ here $u=1, v=dy/dx$

$\partial$ is used when a functions defined on $R^n,n>1$ is differentiated.